# How to build a rolling forward SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have been working on a report that would allow a user to review the totals rolling forward.

This a is matrix.  I have included an sample on what the data looks like.

The report should start the running total from Oct with the amount of $42.  Then the report will sum on the accounts. Then take the $42 + $64 = $106.   The $106 will carry over to the Dec month starting the beginning balance at $106.

Report that I am working on
[image: Report that I am working on]

**Example of the report**

```
                     2016-011            2016-012

Beginning Balance       42                   106

AP                      31                    41
APAJ                    32                    42
CJ                      33                    43
GEN                    -32                   -42

Total Account           64                    84

Begin Bal + Total Acc  106                   190
```

**Example of the data**

```
DECLARE @ClosingBalTemp TABLE
(
  Account_ID varchar(30),
  Period_Nbr varchar(10),
  Source_Code varchar(10),
  Closing_Balance_Amt numeric(16,2)
)

INSERT INTO @ClosingBalTemp (Account_ID, Period_Nbr, Source_Code, Closing_Balance_Amt)

    VALUES ('01-002-333', '2016-008', 'AP', 1),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-008', 'APAJ', 2),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-008', 'CJ', 3),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-008', 'GEN', -2),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-009', 'AP', 11),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-009', 'APAJ', 12),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-009', 'CJ', 13),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-009', 'GEN', -12),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-010', 'AP', 20),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-010', 'APAJ', 21),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-010', 'CJ', 23),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-010', 'GEN', -22),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-011', 'AP', 31),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-011', 'APAJ', 32),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-011', 'CJ', 33),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-011', 'GEN', -32),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-012', 'AP', 41),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-012', 'APAJ', 42),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-012', 'CJ', 43),
           ('01-002-333', '2016-012', 'GEN', -42)

SELECT * FROM @ClosingBalTemp


The data should look like this

The logic is almost working. The Bal type is not calculating the running balance correctly after Period 9. The 4.00 is coming from Oct that does not display.

B   BAL    2016 9   4.00
T   AP     2016 9   11.00
T   APAJ   2016 9   12.00
T   CJ     2016 9   13.00
T   GEN    2016 9   -12.00
B   BAL    2016 10  24.00     **Should be 33**
T   AP     2016 10  20.00
T   APAJ   2016 10  21.00
T   CJ     2016 10  23.00
T   GEN    2016 10  -22.00
B   BAL    2016 11  42.00     **Should be 75**
T   AP     2016 11  31.00
T   APAJ   2016 11  32.00
T   CJ     2016 11  33.00
T   GEN    2016 11  -32.00
B   BAL    2016 12  64.00     **Should be 139**
T   AP     2016 12  41.00
T   APAJ   2016 12  42.00
T   CJ     2016 12  43.00
T   GEN    2016 12  -42.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Running totals are going to work because of the column layout.  We want the top of 2016-012 to come from the bottom of 2016-011. I will say I don't quite understand your data set and I do a lot of roll forwards/trial balances[Hers's s post on Trial blances](http://www.reportsyouneed.com/blog/building-an-ssrs-trial-balance-for-dynamics-gp).  But I do believe I have solved your problem using 2008 stuff with the suggested stored procedure.  Ideally, year and period would be separate fields to make calculating the periods easier. I just hardcoded them for now.
With the output, you can create a column for each month in your SSRS report. You can calculate the month end totals yourself in SSRS.
There may be a better way to do this in 2008 but I don't have 2008 on my server so I can't test. (I would handle the beginning balance summaries differently)

```
DECLARE @CurrentPeriod CHAR(10);
DECLARE @PriorPeriod CHAR(10);
DECLARE @PPPeriod CHAR(10)

SET @CurrentPeriod = '2016-012';
SET @PriorPeriod = '2016-011';
SET @PPPeriod = '2016-010';
-- First Step - Summarize the balances
WITH Balances (CurrentPeriodOpenBal, PriorPeriodOpenBal)
  AS (
     SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN cbt.Period_Nbr IN (@PPPeriod, @PriorPeriod)
            THEN cbt.Closing_Balance_Amt ELSE 0 END)
            AS CurrentPeriodOpenBal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN cbt.Period_Nbr IN (@PPPeriod) 
            THEN cbt.Closing_Balance_Amt ELSE 0 END) 
            AS PriorPeriodOpenBal
        FROM dbo.ClosingBalTemp cbt
        WHERE cbt.Period_Nbr < @CurrentPeriod
  )
-- Now we are going to combine our balances and our transaction
,
BalTrans (TransType, SourceCode, PeriodNbr, Amount) AS
(
SELECT 'B', 'BAL', @PriorPeriod, bal.PriorPeriodOpenBal 
FROM Balances bal   
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B', 'BAL', @CurrentPeriod, bal.CurrentPeriodOpenBal 
FROM Balances  bal
UNION ALL  
SELECT 'T', trans.Source_Code, trans.Period_Nbr,  trans.Closing_Balance_Amt
   FROM dbo.ClosingBalTemp trans
  WHERE trans.Period_Nbr BETWEEN @PriorPeriod AND @CurrentPeriod
)
-- Now we simply order our transactions   
SELECT bt.TransType, bt.SourceCode, bt.PeriodNbr, bt.Amount FROM BalTrans bt
 ORDER BY bt.PeriodNbr, bt.TransType, bt.SourceCode
```

--- Revised Version

```
-- First Step - convert period to fiscla year and period
WITH Trans AS
  (SELECT cbt.Account_ID, 
    cbt.Period_Nbr,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(cbt.Period_Nbr,1,4) AS INT) AS FiscalYear,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(cbt.Period_Nbr,6,3) AS INT) AS FiscalPeriod,
    cbt.Source_Code,
    cbt.Closing_Balance_Amt
    FROM dbo.ClosingBalTemp cbt) 


-- This gets the total balance for each period - we add one to the period
-- to figure out the opening info
, Balances ( FiscalYear, FiscalPeriod, OpenPeriod, Amount)
 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
       bal.FiscalYear,
       bal.FiscalPeriod,
       bal.FiscalPeriod + 1 AS OpenPeriod,
       SUM(bal.Closing_Balance_Amt) OVER(ORDER BY bal.Period_Nbr) AS Amount  
        FROM Trans bal
        WHERE bal.Period_Nbr >= @PPPeriod 
          AND bal.Period_Nbr  < @StartingPeriod
  )
-- Now we are going to combine our balances and our transaction
,

BalTrans (TransType, SourceCode, FiscalYear, FiscalPeriod, Amount) AS
(
 SELECT 'B', 'BAL', bl.FiscalYear, bl.OpenPeriod, bl.Amount FROM Balances bl    
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'T', trans.Source_Code, trans.FiscalYear, trans.FiscalPeriod, 
        trans.Closing_Balance_Amt
FROM Trans trans
WHERE trans.Period_Nbr BETWEEN @EndingPeriod AND @StartingPeriod
)   
SELECT bt.TransType, bt.SourceCode, bt.FiscalYear, Bt.FiscalPeriod,
 bt.Amount FROM BalTrans bt
ORDER BY bt.FiscalYear, bt.FiscalPeriod, bt.TransType, bt.SourceCode
```

-- Example with cursor

```
DECLARE @EndPeriod CHAR(10);
DECLARE @StartPeriod CHAR(10);
DECLARE @PPPeriod CHAR(10)
-- Ideally, year and period would be separate integer fields
-- so one could calculate prior period from current Period.
-- But that's not the key part of the question 
SET @EndPeriod = '2016-012';
SET @StartPeriod = '2016-009';
SET @PPPeriod = '2016-008';

DECLARE @Period_Nbr CHAR(10);
DECLARE @Source_Code CHAR(10);
DECLARE @Closing_Balance_Amt NUMERIC(16,2);

DECLARE @ReportPeriod CHAR(10);
DECLARE @ReportBalance NUMERIC(16,2);

CREATE TABLE #Output 
( ID INTEGER IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,   
  Period_Nbr CHAR(10), 
  Source_Code CHAR(10),
  Closing_Balance_Amt numeric(10,2)
  )
  -- the following insures that SSRS sees the output correctly
IF 1=2
  BEGIN
     SELECT ID,
        Period_Nbr,
        Source_Code,
        Closing_Balance_Amt
        FROM #Output;
  END;

DECLARE OMGUAC CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT Period_Nbr, Source_Code, Closing_Balance_Amt
  FROM dbo.ClosingBalTemp
  WHERE Period_Nbr BETWEEN @PPPeriod AND @EndPeriod
  ORDER BY Period_Nbr, Source_Code;

OPEN OMGUAC;

FETCH NEXT FROM OMGUAC INTO @Period_Nbr,@Source_Code,@Closing_Balance_Amt;

SET @ReportPeriod = @Period_Nbr;
SET @ReportBalance = 0;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN 
    -- When the period Changes, print the opening balance
     IF @Period_Nbr <> @ReportPeriod    
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO #Output
                ( Period_Nbr ,
                  Source_Code ,
                  Closing_Balance_Amt
                )
            VALUES  (@Period_Nbr, 'Open Bal',@ReportBalance);
        END
 IF @Period_Nbr > @PPPeriod
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO #Output
                ( Period_Nbr ,
                  Source_Code ,
                  Closing_Balance_Amt
                )
        VALUES  (@Period_Nbr, @Source_Code,@Closing_Balance_Amt);
    END
  SET @ReportBalance = @ReportBalance + @Closing_Balance_Amt;
  SET @ReportPeriod = @Period_Nbr
  FETCH NEXT FROM OMGUAC INTO @Period_Nbr, @Source_Code,
 @Closing_Balance_Amt;
   END;
SELECT * FROM #Output 
ORDER BY ID;
DROP TABLE #Output;
CLOSE OMGUAC;
DEALLOCATE OMGUAC;
```

Comment: Hi Adam, Wow! Thanks for your help.  This is great... I have a small problem.  If you enter 2016-009 for previous period and 2016-008 for previous previous period and 2016-012 for current period the BAL is not calculating for 2016-010 or 2016-011.  Its not calculating for the periods that are within the select period range. The report should work whatever period range that are entered.

Comment: First, I'd ask that you accept my answer. Thanks.  Next, your question didn't specify how you were going to make selections - how many periods, how was that going to be answered, so I assumed from the output that you were selecting two months.  Specify what you imagine the options (and the columns), and the answer should be pretty easy to adjust

Comment: Hi Adam,  Sorry for that.  Yes I did not explain how the data would be selected.  The data is selected on a Date Range 08/01/16 - 12/31/16.  I convert the 2 dates to get the start and ending periods.  Then base on the number of periods will be the column heading except the Previous Previous period.  I am only getting the starting Beginning balance from that period.  After that the sum of each period will be the beginning balance the next period.  This will happen until all period are displayed.

Comment: I've added another set of code after the first
I've split your fiscal year and period into two fields.  YOu can edit to get things back.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for the quick response. :Look like SQL 2008 does not support OVER().   http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47116/in-microsoft-sql-server-2008-syntax-generates-the-error-the-parallel-data-ware.

Comment: I thought about this.  Given the very specific request, my skills (and knowledge of 2008) means that I would go with a cursor, looping through the records and putting out a roll forward balance when the period changed.  I haven't had time to write that up.  do you have any experience with cursors?

Comment: Wow!  Thanks Thanks Adam.  This is good stuff.  This is working for me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at runningvalue() here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255229.aspx
This can be used with a group as the scope, so can be used on your column group.